# £ considered invalid character

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, gsub

I need to search for a "£" sign in my text but it keeps coming up with the error:

```
invalid character property name {`£`}: /\p{`\u00A3`}/ (SyntaxError)
```

i have # encoding: utf-8 at the top, the context in which I'm using it is:

```
 original_contents << line.gsub(/[abc]/, '*')
 .gsub(/\p{£}/, '')
```

When I try `.gsub(/£/, '')` instead, I get

```
C:/Users...Epub run through.rb:12:in `gsub': incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with CP850 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
  from C:/Users...Epub run through.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from C:/Users...Epub run through.rb:9:in `each_line'
  from C:/Users...Epub run through.rb:9:in `<top (required)>' 
  from -e:1:in `load'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `.gsub(/£/, '')` works. ruby 2.0, windows 7

Comment: it works for me on ruby 2.1.3, what version are you using?

Comment: i'm using ruby 1.9.3, windows 7. i'll try updating, thanks

Comment: ok so i've updated to 2.0 and it's coming up with the same errors

Comment: `line.gsub(/[abc]/, '*').gsub(/£/, '')` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In a regexp, `\p` is for matching a "character property" which is basically a set of characters that are related in some way (e.g. digit charaters, ASCII characters, etc.). The documentation lists the character properties [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties). According to that list (and your error message), that's an invalid character property in your  code.

You should just use `/£/`. The error you're getting in *that* case is because your string is not UTF-8 encoded. Regexps use source encoding by default (which is UTF-8) and should match the encoding of the string. The easiest way to fix that is to change the string's encoding.

```
original_contents.encode! Encoding::UTF_8
original_contents.gsub(/£/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "invalid character property name", and that is correct. The valid Unicode character property names are:

- Alpha
- Blank
- Cntrl
- Digit
- Graph
- Lower
- Print
- Punct
- Space
- Upper
- XDigit
- Word
- Alnum
- ASCII
- Any
- Assigned
- C
- Cc
- Cf
- Cn
- Co
- Cs
- L
- LC
- Ll
- Lm
- Lo
- Lt
- Lu
- M
- Mc
- Me
- Mn
- N
- Nd
- Nl
- No
- P
- Pc
- Pd
- Pe
- Pf
- Pi
- Po
- Ps
- S
- Sc
- Sk
- Sm
- So
- Z
- Zl
- Zp
- Zs
- Arabic
- Armenian
- Avestan
- Balinese
- Bamum
- Bassa_Vah
- Batak
- Bengali
- Bopomofo
- Brahmi
- Braille
- Buginese
- Buhid
- Canadian_Aboriginal
- Carian
- Caucasian_Albanian
- Chakma
- Cham
- Cherokee
- Common
- Coptic
- Cuneiform
- Cypriot
- Cyrillic
- Deseret
- Devanagari
- Duployan
- Egyptian_Hieroglyphs
- Elbasan
- Ethiopic
- Georgian
- Glagolitic
- Gothic
- Grantha
- Greek
- Gujarati
- Gurmukhi
- Han
- Hangul
- Hanunoo
- Hebrew
- Hiragana
- Imperial_Aramaic
- Inherited
- Inscriptional_Pahlavi
- Inscriptional_Parthian
- Javanese
- Kaithi
- Kannada
- Katakana
- Kayah_Li
- Kharoshthi
- Khmer
- Khojki
- Khudawadi
- Lao
- Latin
- Lepcha
- Limbu
- Linear_A
- Linear_B
- Lisu
- Lycian
- Lydian
- Mahajani
- Malayalam
- Mandaic
- Manichaean
- Meetei_Mayek
- Mende_Kikakui
- Meroitic_Cursive
- Meroitic_Hieroglyphs
- Miao
- Modi
- Mongolian
- Mro
- Myanmar
- Nabataean
- New_Tai_Lue
- Nko
- Ogham
- Ol_Chiki
- Old_Italic
- Old_North_Arabian
- Old_Permic
- Old_Persian
- Old_South_Arabian
- Old_Turkic
- Oriya
- Osmanya
- Pahawh_Hmong
- Palmyrene
- Pau_Cin_Hau
- Phags_Pa
- Phoenician
- Psalter_Pahlavi
- Rejang
- Runic
- Samaritan
- Saurashtra
- Sharada
- Shavian
- Siddham
- Sinhala
- Sora_Sompeng
- Sundanese
- Syloti_Nagri
- Syriac
- Tagalog
- Tagbanwa
- Tai_Le
- Tai_Tham
- Tai_Viet
- Takri
- Tamil
- Telugu
- Thaana
- Thai
- Tibetan
- Tifinagh
- Tirhuta
- Ugaritic
- Unknown
- Vai
- Warang_Citi
- Yi
- Alphabetic
- Case_Ignorable
- Cased
- Changes_When_Casefolded
- Changes_When_Casemapped
- Changes_When_Lowercased
- Changes_When_Titlecased
- Changes_When_Uppercased
- Default_Ignorable_Code_Point
- Grapheme_Base
- Grapheme_Extend
- Grapheme_Link
- ID_Continue
- ID_Start
- Lowercase
- Math
- Uppercase
- XID_Continue
- XID_Start
- ASCII_Hex_Digit
- Bidi_Control
- Dash
- Deprecated
- Diacritic
- Extender
- Hex_Digit
- Hyphen
- IDS_Binary_Operator
- IDS_Trinary_Operator
- Ideographic
- Join_Control
- Logical_Order_Exception
- Noncharacter_Code_Point
- Other_Alphabetic
- Other_Default_Ignorable_Code_Point
- Other_Grapheme_Extend
- Other_ID_Continue
- Other_ID_Start
- Other_Lowercase
- Other_Math
- Other_Uppercase
- Pattern_Syntax
- Pattern_White_Space
- Quotation_Mark
- Radical
- STerm
- Soft_Dotted
- Terminal_Punctuation
- Unified_Ideograph
- Variation_Selector
- White_Space
- AHex
- Bidi_C
- CI
- CWCF
- CWCM
- CWL
- CWT
- CWU
- DI
- Dep
- Dia
- Ext
- Gr_Base
- Gr_Ext
- Gr_Link
- Hex
- IDC
- IDS
- IDSB
- IDST
- Ideo
- Join_C
- LOE
- NChar
- OAlpha
- ODI
- OGr_Ext
- OIDC
- OIDS
- OLower
- OMath
- OUpper
- Pat_Syn
- Pat_WS
- QMark
- SD
- Term
- UIdeo
- VS
- WSpace
- XIDC
- XIDS
- Other
- Control
- Format
- Unassigned
- Private_Use
- Surrogate
- Letter
- Cased_Letter
- Lowercase_Letter
- Modifier_Letter
- Other_Letter
- Titlecase_Letter
- Uppercase_Letter
- Mark
- Combining_Mark
- Spacing_Mark
- Enclosing_Mark
- Nonspacing_Mark
- Number
- Decimal_Number
- Letter_Number
- Other_Number
- Punctuation
- Connector_Punctuation
- Dash_Punctuation
- Close_Punctuation
- Final_Punctuation
- Initial_Punctuation
- Other_Punctuation
- Open_Punctuation
- Symbol
- Currency_Symbol
- Modifier_Symbol
- Math_Symbol
- Other_Symbol
- Separator
- Line_Separator
- Paragraph_Separator
- Space_Separator
- Aghb
- Arab
- Armi
- Armn
- Avst
- Bali
- Bamu
- Bass
- Batk
- Beng
- Bopo
- Brah
- Brai
- Bugi
- Buhd
- Cakm
- Cans
- Cari
- Cher
- Copt
- Qaac
- Cprt
- Cyrl
- Deva
- Dsrt
- Dupl
- Egyp
- Elba
- Ethi
- Geor
- Glag
- Goth
- Gran
- Grek
- Gujr
- Guru
- Hang
- Hani
- Hano
- Hebr
- Hira
- Hmng
- Ital
- Java
- Kali
- Kana
- Khar
- Khmr
- Khoj
- Knda
- Kthi
- Lana
- Laoo
- Latn
- Lepc
- Limb
- Lina
- Linb
- Lyci
- Lydi
- Mahj
- Mand
- Mani
- Mend
- Merc
- Mero
- Mlym
- Mong
- Mroo
- Mtei
- Mymr
- Narb
- Nbat
- Nkoo
- Ogam
- Olck
- Orkh
- Orya
- Osma
- Palm
- Pauc
- Perm
- Phag
- Phli
- Phlp
- Phnx
- Plrd
- Prti
- Rjng
- Runr
- Samr
- Sarb
- Saur
- Shaw
- Shrd
- Sidd
- Sind
- Sinh
- Sora
- Sund
- Sylo
- Syrc
- Tagb
- Takr
- Tale
- Talu
- Taml
- Tavt
- Telu
- Tfng
- Tglg
- Thaa
- Tibt
- Tirh
- Ugar
- Vaii
- Wara
- Xpeo
- Xsux
- Yiii
- Zinh
- Qaai
- Zyyy
- Zzzz
- Age=1.1
- Age=2.0
- Age=2.1
- Age=3.0
- Age=3.1
- Age=3.2
- Age=4.0
- Age=4.1
- Age=5.0
- Age=5.1
- Age=5.2
- Age=6.0
- Age=6.1
- Age=6.2
- Age=6.3
- Age=7.0
- In_Basic_Latin
- In_Latin_1_Supplement
- In_Latin_Extended_A
- In_Latin_Extended_B
- In_IPA_Extensions
- In_Spacing_Modifier_Letters
- In_Combining_Diacritical_Marks
- In_Greek_and_Coptic
- In_Cyrillic
- In_Cyrillic_Supplement
- In_Armenian
- In_Hebrew
- In_Arabic
- In_Syriac
- In_Arabic_Supplement
- In_Thaana
- In_NKo
- In_Samaritan
- In_Mandaic
- In_Arabic_Extended_A
- In_Devanagari
- In_Bengali
- In_Gurmukhi
- In_Gujarati
- In_Oriya
- In_Tamil
- In_Telugu
- In_Kannada
- In_Malayalam
- In_Sinhala
- In_Thai
- In_Lao
- In_Tibetan
- In_Myanmar
- In_Georgian
- In_Hangul_Jamo
- In_Ethiopic
- In_Ethiopic_Supplement
- In_Cherokee
- In_Unified_Canadian_Aboriginal_Syllabics
- In_Ogham
- In_Runic
- In_Tagalog
- In_Hanunoo
- In_Buhid
- In_Tagbanwa
- In_Khmer
- In_Mongolian
- In_Unified_Canadian_Aboriginal_Syllabics_Extended
- In_Limbu
- In_Tai_Le
- In_New_Tai_Lue
- In_Khmer_Symbols
- In_Buginese
- In_Tai_Tham
- In_Combining_Diacritical_Marks_Extended
- In_Balinese
- In_Sundanese
- In_Batak
- In_Lepcha
- In_Ol_Chiki
- In_Sundanese_Supplement
- In_Vedic_Extensions
- In_Phonetic_Extensions
- In_Phonetic_Extensions_Supplement
- In_Combining_Diacritical_Marks_Supplement
- In_Latin_Extended_Additional
- In_Greek_Extended
- In_General_Punctuation
- In_Superscripts_and_Subscripts
- In_Currency_Symbols
- In_Combining_Diacritical_Marks_for_Symbols
- In_Letterlike_Symbols
- In_Number_Forms
- In_Arrows
- In_Mathematical_Operators
- In_Miscellaneous_Technical
- In_Control_Pictures
- In_Optical_Character_Recognition
- In_Enclosed_Alphanumerics
- In_Box_Drawing
- In_Block_Elements
- In_Geometric_Shapes
- In_Miscellaneous_Symbols
- In_Dingbats
- In_Miscellaneous_Mathematical_Symbols_A
- In_Supplemental_Arrows_A
- In_Braille_Patterns
- In_Supplemental_Arrows_B
- In_Miscellaneous_Mathematical_Symbols_B
- In_Supplemental_Mathematical_Operators
- In_Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Arrows
- In_Glagolitic
- In_Latin_Extended_C
- In_Coptic
- In_Georgian_Supplement
- In_Tifinagh
- In_Ethiopic_Extended
- In_Cyrillic_Extended_A
- In_Supplemental_Punctuation
- In_CJK_Radicals_Supplement
- In_Kangxi_Radicals
- In_Ideographic_Description_Characters
- In_CJK_Symbols_and_Punctuation
- In_Hiragana
- In_Katakana
- In_Bopomofo
- In_Hangul_Compatibility_Jamo
- In_Kanbun
- In_Bopomofo_Extended
- In_CJK_Strokes
- In_Katakana_Phonetic_Extensions
- In_Enclosed_CJK_Letters_and_Months
- In_CJK_Compatibility
- In_CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_A
- In_Yijing_Hexagram_Symbols
- In_CJK_Unified_Ideographs
- In_Yi_Syllables
- In_Yi_Radicals
- In_Lisu
- In_Vai
- In_Cyrillic_Extended_B
- In_Bamum
- In_Modifier_Tone_Letters
- In_Latin_Extended_D
- In_Syloti_Nagri
- In_Common_Indic_Number_Forms
- In_Phags_pa
- In_Saurashtra
- In_Devanagari_Extended
- In_Kayah_Li
- In_Rejang
- In_Hangul_Jamo_Extended_A
- In_Javanese
- In_Myanmar_Extended_B
- In_Cham
- In_Myanmar_Extended_A
- In_Tai_Viet
- In_Meetei_Mayek_Extensions
- In_Ethiopic_Extended_A
- In_Latin_Extended_E
- In_Meetei_Mayek
- In_Hangul_Syllables
- In_Hangul_Jamo_Extended_B
- In_High_Surrogates
- In_High_Private_Use_Surrogates
- In_Low_Surrogates
- In_Private_Use_Area
- In_CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs
- In_Alphabetic_Presentation_Forms
- In_Arabic_Presentation_Forms_A
- In_Variation_Selectors
- In_Vertical_Forms
- In_Combining_Half_Marks
- In_CJK_Compatibility_Forms
- In_Small_Form_Variants
- In_Arabic_Presentation_Forms_B
- In_Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms
- In_Specials
- In_Linear_B_Syllabary
- In_Linear_B_Ideograms
- In_Aegean_Numbers
- In_Ancient_Greek_Numbers
- In_Ancient_Symbols
- In_Phaistos_Disc
- In_Lycian
- In_Carian
- In_Coptic_Epact_Numbers
- In_Old_Italic
- In_Gothic
- In_Old_Permic
- In_Ugaritic
- In_Old_Persian
- In_Deseret
- In_Shavian
- In_Osmanya
- In_Elbasan
- In_Caucasian_Albanian
- In_Linear_A
- In_Cypriot_Syllabary
- In_Imperial_Aramaic
- In_Palmyrene
- In_Nabataean
- In_Phoenician
- In_Lydian
- In_Meroitic_Hieroglyphs
- In_Meroitic_Cursive
- In_Kharoshthi
- In_Old_South_Arabian
- In_Old_North_Arabian
- In_Manichaean
- In_Avestan
- In_Inscriptional_Parthian
- In_Inscriptional_Pahlavi
- In_Psalter_Pahlavi
- In_Old_Turkic
- In_Rumi_Numeral_Symbols
- In_Brahmi
- In_Kaithi
- In_Sora_Sompeng
- In_Chakma
- In_Mahajani
- In_Sharada
- In_Sinhala_Archaic_Numbers
- In_Khojki
- In_Khudawadi
- In_Grantha
- In_Tirhuta
- In_Siddham
- In_Modi
- In_Takri
- In_Warang_Citi
- In_Pau_Cin_Hau
- In_Cuneiform
- In_Cuneiform_Numbers_and_Punctuation
- In_Egyptian_Hieroglyphs
- In_Bamum_Supplement
- In_Mro
- In_Bassa_Vah
- In_Pahawh_Hmong
- In_Miao
- In_Kana_Supplement
- In_Duployan
- In_Shorthand_Format_Controls
- In_Byzantine_Musical_Symbols
- In_Musical_Symbols
- In_Ancient_Greek_Musical_Notation
- In_Tai_Xuan_Jing_Symbols
- In_Counting_Rod_Numerals
- In_Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols
- In_Mende_Kikakui
- In_Arabic_Mathematical_Alphabetic_Symbols
- In_Mahjong_Tiles
- In_Domino_Tiles
- In_Playing_Cards
- In_Enclosed_Alphanumeric_Supplement
- In_Enclosed_Ideographic_Supplement
- In_Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs
- In_Emoticons
- In_Ornamental_Dingbats
- In_Transport_and_Map_Symbols
- In_Alchemical_Symbols
- In_Geometric_Shapes_Extended
- In_Supplemental_Arrows_C
- In_CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_B
- In_CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_C
- In_CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_D
- In_CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs_Supplement
- In_Tags
- In_Variation_Selectors_Supplement
- In_Supplementary_Private_Use_Area_A
- In_Supplementary_Private_Use_Area_B
- In_No_Block

As you can see, "£" is not a valid Unicode property name.

Comment: Jörg, thanks for the reminder. I had forgotten about `In_Tifinagh`.